# getJSON is adding the previos URL. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, get, getjson

I have an Spring Server with HTML pages with Thymeleaf Engine and I am using jQuery for making a getJSON:

When my server is redirecting to that URL `localhost:8080/redirect_admin/` where is the the next peace of code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
     <td>
       <input type="text" class="add_youtube_link" th:id="${id_local}"  />
       <input type="button" id="upload_youtube_links" onclick="add_youtube_link()" value="Add new Youtube Link"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Where I can add a link to add in my server. Well, when I click on `onclick` the next Javascript function will run:

```
function add_youtube_link()
{
   var url2 = "add_youtube_link/"+$(".add_youtube_link").attr('id')+"/"+$(".add_youtube_link").val().replace(/\//g,"_");
   alert(url2);
   $.getJSON(url2, function (data) {
   //  window.location = "redirect_media/"+$(".add_youtube_link").attr('id');
   });
}
```

So, the alert function is showing correctly the new URL: `add_youtube_link/1/ZyDO4FUVxXk` untill this point all is OK.

But, if I take a look in the Network Log on Chrome, the URL called is:

`GET http://localhost:8080/redirect_media/add_youtube_link/1/ZyDO4FUVxXk  404 (Not Found)` .

So, the problem is that the previous URL `redirect_admin/` is adding automatically in the new URL. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Try with `var url2 = "/add_youtube_link`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its always a good idea to use a base url in your code, so you don't face issues like this:

```
var baseUrl = location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + (location.port && ":" + location.port) + "/";
```

Then include that base url with any url

```
var url2 = baseUrl + "add_youtube_link/"+$(".add_youtube_link").attr('id')+"/"+$(".add_youtube_link").val().replace(/\//g,"_");
```

Comment: Thank you for the information! Luckily, with the @juvian reference i have solved the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Usually this kind of error happens when your physical script file's address is different from your html page.The solution is that we always pass the partial address from the context where the function is called and in this case is your html page.